# How to validate a RSA SHA1 signature in C++ generated in a java program

Tags: java, c++, rsa, sha1, crypto++

We have a java program that signs a xml file with a private key like this:

```
byte[] privateKeyBytes = ...; // read from the .der file
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privateSpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privateKeyBytes);
KeyFactory privateKeyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PrivateKey = privateKeyFactory.generatePrivate(privateSpec);

Signature rsaSignature = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
rsaSignature.initSign(privateKey);
rsaSignature.update(data);

byte[] signature = rsaSignature.sign();
```

Now i have to validate this signature in C++ using cryptocpp. What i tried:

```
void Load(const std::string& filename, BufferedTransformation& bt)
{
    FileSource file(filename.c_str(), true /*pumpAll*/);
    file.TransferTo(bt);
    bt.MessageEnd();
}
void LoadKeyFile(const std::string& filename, PublicKey & key)
{
    ByteQueue queue;
    Load(filename, queue);
    key.Load(queue);    
}
    
void verifySignature(std::string xmlString, std::string signature)
{
    RSA::PublicKey publicKey;
    LoadKeyFile(..., publicKey);
    RSASS<PSS, SHA1>::Verifier verifier(publicKey);   
    // also tried RSASS<PSSR, SHA1>::Verifier verifier(publicKey);   
    
    
    if (!verifier.VerifyMessage((byte*)xmlString.c_str(), xmlString.size(),  
                                (byte*)signature.c_str(), signature.size()) )
    {
         // always returns false
    }
}
```

I validated that the data passed as xmlString is binary identical with the one used for creating the signature in java. The signature is base64 encoded and i also tried using it decoded.
I always failed so far.

If i create a signature with the private key using cryptopp - then validating the created signature works without problems.

What may be the problem here? I am sure this has already been done?

Comment: At least the paddings seem to be inconsistent, the Java code uses PKCS#1 v1.5 for `SHA1withRSA`, the C/C++ code applies PSS for `RSASS<PSS, SHA1>`.

Comment: @Topaco - thanks for your answer - Is there a way to add this padding to cryprocpp? I didnt find any.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://cryptopp.com/wiki/RSA_Signature_Schemes#Signature_Scheme_.28PKCS_v1.5.29). Maybe this will help.

Comment: @Topaco! Thanks for the hint. see my own answer!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is

```
RSASS<PKCS1v15, SHA1>::Verifier verifier(publicKey);
```

Instead of

```
RSASS<PSS, SHA1>::Verifier verifier(publicKey);
```

Thanks a lot to @Topaco!